# Displaying radio button choice php?

Tags: php

My code works fine after the form fill out all values are print accept my gender value.

Here in the code below is an example imagine firstName,lastName.... the `$row[dob]` value prints out successfully.

But the option for the gender is not printing is there some array function i need to use for this to have the option selected bu the user print back on the screen when only display the details of the user (similar to a sticky form)?

```
    <li><label for='dateOfBirth'>DOB:</label>
    <input type='date' name='dateOfBirth' value = $row[dob] min='1900-01-01' max= '2015-01-01'/></li>

    <li>
        <input type='radio' name='gender' value=$row[gender]'>
        <label for='male'>Male</label><br>
        <input type='radio' name='gender' value='female'>
        <label for='female'>Female</label><br>
    </li>
```

Comment: I assume this entire sample of code is inside an `echo "..."` statement, otherwise the variable values wouldn't be printing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use the `checked` attribute

if the value that comes from `$row['gender']` is **male** check the male radio otherwise check the **female**

like this

```
<li>
     <input type='radio' name='gender' <?= $row[gender] == 'male'? 'checked':'' ?> value='male'>
     <label for='male'>Male</label><br>
     <input type='radio' name='gender' <?= $row[gender] == 'female'? 'checked':'' ?> value='female'>
     <label for='female'>Female</label><br>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't set the value of the radio inputs, instead determine if the value is checked.

Example:

```
<li>
    <input type='radio' name='gender' value='male' <?= $row['gender'] === 'male' ? 'checked' : null ?>>
    <label for='male'>Male</label><br>
    <input type='radio' name='gender' value='female' <?= $row['gender'] === 'female' ? 'checked' : null ?>>
    <label for='female'>Female</label><br>
</li>
```

**NOTE:** Your condition `<?= $row['gender'] === 'female' ? 'checked' : null ?>` may vary depending on how you template your HTML.

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4734164a8e9caea7602838b09ea6a645f0d5c867)